# Is there a way to add a badge on marker in react-leaflet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I have tried using ant design badge, normally it works when you put it on icon but no luck with react-leaflet marker. Here is what i have tried

```
<Badge count={5}>
  <Marker icon = {sideTipperIcon} position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
    <Tooltip direction='top'>
      Leading: Overload <br />
      Lagging: Utilization
    </Tooltip>
  </Marker>
</Badge>
```

In this scenario the badge does not show so is there any way to show a badge on this leaflet marker?

Comment: A bootstrap badge? Where to show it? In the popup?

Comment: on top of the marker like this https://ant.design/components/badge/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if it can be achieved via the link you provided. 
You can construct your own badge marker component like this:

```
const MarkerWithBadge = props => {
  const initMarker = ref => {
    if (ref) {
      const popup = L.popup().setContent(props.children);
      ref.leafletElement
        .addTo(ref.contextValue.map)
        .bindPopup(popup, {
          className: "badge",
          closeOnClick: false,
          autoClose: false
        })
        .openPopup()
        // prevent badge from dissapearing onClick
        .off("click");
    }
  };
  return <Marker ref={initMarker} {...props} />;
};
```

badge css selector:

```
.badge .leaflet-popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: -12px;
  z-index: 10;
  min-width: 20px;
  width: 5px !important;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f5222d;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
<Map style={{ height: "100vh" }} center={position} zoom={this.state.zoom}>
     <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
     />
     <MarkerWithBadge position={position} icon={customMarker}>
       5
     </MarkerWithBadge>
</Map>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/add-a-badge-on-marker-in-react-leaflet-cjziy)

Comment: one complication onClick function is not working i have tried it like this 
```<Marker ref={initMarker} {...props} onClick={() => console.log('---')}/>```
and also like this ```<MarkerWithBadge icon = {sideTipperIcon} tooltip={{leading: 'Overload', lagging: 'Utilization'}} position={[51.505, -0.09]} onClick={() => console.log('-------')}>
        5
       </MarkerWithBadge>```

Comment: This happens because I have deactivated the click event in order not to hide the badge when clicking on the marker. If you comment this line `.off("click");` it should work.